# Reading binary TCP data: the correct stream type

Tags: java

In my readMessage function, I get the error message "OutputStream is abstract; cannot be instantiated." Which data type should I use to store the read data? Please disregard that the return value is String.

```
private String readMessage() throws IOException {
  byte[] messageChunk = new byte[1024];
  int bytesRead = 0;
  OutputStream messageData = new OutputStream();

  boolean end = false;

  while ( !end ) {
    bytesRead = in.read(messageChunk);
    if ( bytesRead > 2 && messageChunk[bytesRead - 2] == '\r' ) end = true; // TODO: is -2 correct?
    else if ( bytesRead == 1 && messageChunk[bytesRead - 1] == '\n' ) end = true;
    messageData.write(messageChunk, 0, bytesRead);
  }

  return messageData.toString();
}
```

Comment: depends on where you want to store the data. If in a file, use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: I want to process the data further. The protocol that I follow uses mixed text and binary data.

Comment: You may want to use a `ByteChannel` in that case. Do you at least have an idea of the length of the different parts?

Comment: Yes - the length is transferred before the binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because OutputStream class is an abstract class. you cant create instances from abstract classes using new keyword without the implementation.

why dont you use `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `OutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though what you want isn't any of this, but rather simply a `BufferedReader`, and this entire method reduces to `return reader.readLine();` But I don't know why you're sending length-words *and* line terminators. Have a think about your application protocol.

Comment: The protocol uses mixed binary and text data. E.g. a read message could be "SENDING 5 BYTES LONG DATA: ř)#4í\r\n"